# Option From collection for select and user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I have a small form partial where you have he option to choose through users to add as a collaborator.

```
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.premium, "id", "username") %>
```

But and it give me a list of all premium users BUT i want to be able to see Premium and Admin users.

Ive tried `(User.premium ||  User.admin)`

but it doesnt seem to work i still get premium users only .

Comment: i cant understand what exactly u want to select ? list of dropdown with 'premium' or 'admin' or 'basic' smth like this ? also yr `User.premium` is wrong.

Comment: Im trying to a dropdown list of users that are premium(1) and admin(2). why is my User.premium wrong ?

Comment: The reason `User.premium || User.admin` didn't work is that `||` is a Boolean operator. In Ruby it returns the first operand that is truthy, so e.g. `true || false` returns `true` and `nil || 10` returns `10`. Everything in Ruby except `false` and `nil` is truthy, including the ActiveRecord::Relation object returned by `User.premium`, so that is the value returned by `User.premium || User.admin` (and `User.admin` is never evaluated). If you instead wrote `User.admin || User.premium`, the result of `User.admin` would be returned and `User.premium` wouldn't be evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to provide all data for your view in your controller. Which means you should not be making an database queries in your view. Instead, prepare all required variables in your controller.

#### Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.where(type: ['premium', 'admin'])
  end
end
```

#### View

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "username") %>

<!-- OR shorter -->
<%= f.collection_select :user_id, @users, :id, :username %>
```

Comment: This one should cover everything `<%= f.select :user_id, User.where(type: ['premium', 'admin']) %>`

Comment: Yes! All model access should happen well outside the view. And again I say,  Yes!

Answer (score -1):

Try using an OR condition. Assuming type of user is stored in `type` column of the `user` table

```
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.where("type = 'premium' OR type = 'admin'"), "id", "username") %>
```

Comment: why the downvote? this is similar to the above answer and it works